# JSch: support for ed25519 keys

Tags: java, ssh

There are a couple of SSH libraries for Java. In the past I've used Maverick and Trilead. At least the latter seems to be dead. Now it is time to search a new one that's most likely to be best supported, e.g. regarding ed25519 keys. How to get JSch working with ed25519 keys?

Comment: https://github.com/str4d/ed25519-java is one of java implementation, it is a security provider, have support for OID 1.3.101.112 and should work fine with any common java program. But use it on your own risk. Source code is available, you can check if it contains bugs or vulnerabilites.

Comment: How to get that working with JSch?

Comment: I am not familiar with jsch, but in any java program it should work, if you Include source code, add set somewhere in static block custom SecurityProvider as `java.security.Security.addProvider(new net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.EdDSASecurityProvider())` before reading keys.

Comment: @ThomasS. did you find any solution for that ?

Comment: @MithunSarkerShuvro: we switched to SSHJ instead.

Comment: fork of jsch https://github.com/mwiede/jsch supports ed25519 using Java JEP 339 https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/339 But you need JDK 15

Comment: I'm able to use jsch + BouncyCastle, with the new format  `BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY` keys, but not if they are password protected.